# Setting cookie from webservice call out in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Can somebody please explain me the below?

```
stub.inputHttpheaders_x.put('Cookie', 'name = value');
```

What is 'name = value' in this case?

I am getting the cookie as below:

```
stub.outputHttpheaders_x.get('Set-cookie');
```

How do i use this cookie in the first statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anutosh: Is this code in *SFDC Apex*? If so, I believe you can use: `req.setHeader`: Find the place in your code where you actually make the request and add the cookie to the header like so: req.setHeader('Cookie','sid='+sid);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get hold of the stub, you can set the HTTP Header fields using the inputHttpheaders_x.put method.

This [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header) has a good description of what fields you can set on a HTTP Header. One of these fields to set is "Cookie". It can be set to a "key=value" value for e.g. "site=google".

The code block

```
stub.inputHttpheaders_x.put('Cookie', 'name = value');
```

sets the value 'name = value' to the Cookie header field.

Similarly, you can access cookie value set in the HTTP Headers on a response object using:

```
String cookie = stub.outputHttpHeaders_x.get('Set-Cookie')
```

Hope this makes sense!

Anup
P.S: If you are trying this with a proper integration setup. Try printing the values out to understand the format of the output.

Comment: Hi Anup, Thanks for your response. I am trying the access NetDocs api from salesforce. Netdocs has two wsdl. One contains the login method and other contains the search method. Login method returns the cookie which I can access by 'set-cookie'. My question is how to bind or use this cookie for the search method available in second wsdl. Hope my query is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Anup. I figured out myself.

Comment: If the solution is different from my solution you can add it as an answer to your question, and mark it as accepted. Or if it exactly the same as mine, you can mark my answer as "accepted" so that it helps others when they search for a similar query.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise:

You have to "enable" outputHttpHeaders_x by initialize the map fist
Afterwards you can access the Set-Cookie.

Can be read here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm

> The value of outputHttpHeaders_x is null by default. You must set outputHttpHeaders_x before you have access to the content of headers in the response.

```
docSample.DocSamplePort stub = new docSample.DocSamplePort();
stub.outputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
String input = 'This is the input string';
String output = stub.EchoString(input);

//Getting cookie header
String cookie = stub.outputHttpHeaders_x.get('Set-Cookie');

//Getting custom header
String myHeader = stub.outputHttpHeaders_x.get('My-Header');
```